# No man for tail command

Tags: centos, man, tail

I am using centos 7, but it's weird that I can not get the man page for command tail. Do I miss anything ? Thanks

```
[zeppelin@sandbox zeppelin-zjffdu]$ man tail
No manual entry for tail
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the `man` package installed (It's called man-db in Arch Linux anyway)? Can you do `man man`? How about `man 1 tail`?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the man packages installed:

`yum list man-pages man-db`

If you get no output, then you can install them with:

`yum install man-pages man-db`

The test with `man tail`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Centos would not be showing it but here it is online:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.